# Textbox in safari is not taking the entire string from Selenium+Python Script

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, safari

I'm running the following code on Safari Browser, using Selenium and Python.

```
player=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='settings-stream-confirm']").clear()
player.send_keys("test123")
```

Everytime send_keys enters only the first alphabet of the string ie."t" in the textbox. Any idea how I can enter the entire string into the text-box?

Safari:13.0
Selenium:3.141.0
Python:3.7

Comment: This is wrong locator `driver.find_element_by_xpath("text-box")`, please share the HTML.

Comment: can you add the URL you are trying to access to the question?

Comment: @frianH, I've edited it to the exact code I'm using. Also if xpath were wrong, how will it always enter the first alphabet of the string?

Comment: @Sashaank. I'm sorry but I'm afraid I can't do that. It is an internal testing website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using `ActionChains` or `.execute_script`

- **ActionChains**:

  ```
  player = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='settings-stream-confirm']")
  action = ActionChains(driver)
  action.move_to_element(player).send_keys('test1234').perform()
  ```
- **.execute_script**:

  ```
  player = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='settings-stream-confirm']")
  driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'test1234';", player)
  ```

Btw, based on code in the question, you wrong `player` initialize, please remove `.click()`

Comment: I'm sorry it was .clear(). Clear command was working and I was able to clear the text-box  but not able to enter anything except first character.

Comment: execute_script worked for me and able to enter the string.
action class has been giving me "move_to requires a webelement" error.
Any idea what might be the issue?